# What does "..., with similar emphases arrived at partially independently." mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone help me understand the meaning of the bolded part of the following passage from [*The Meaning of Anxiety* by Rollo May](https://books.google.dk/books?id=bOtyCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT110&ots=0AewYpy1He&#v=onepage):

> Behind statements like these lies Adler’s whole positive evaluation of the social nature of man, an emphasis radically different from Freud’s and involving radically different implications for the overcoming of anxiety. Despite his oversimplifications and generalities, Adler has contributed perdurable insights, particularly in the realm of the power struggles between persons and their social implications. These insights are especially valuable because they generally occur in the areas of Freud’s “blind spots”.
>
> As will be indicated later, the valuable insights of Adler have to a large extent been incorporated in more systematic and profound form as parts of the emphases of such later psychoanalysts as Horney, Fromm, and Sullivan. The influence of Adler on later analysts is no doubt both direct and indirect, **with similar emphases arrived at partially independently**.

To me the confusing part is: “…, with similar emphases arrived at partially independently.”

Comment: I don't recognise this use of (pluralised) ***emphasis***, but I'm guessing it applies to the aspects of Adler's work that later analysts *emphasise / place importance on.* Different analysts sometimes choose *similar / the same* aspects to focus on - partly these are *independent* choices, but to some extent they discuss / collaborate with each other to decide what's important about Adler's work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I found the surrounding text on Google Books and have added a link and more context, which shows that it is rather the later analysts’ various areas of emphasis within the models they set up. It’s not very elegantly written, but _emphases_ does make more sense with better context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ah right. Given ***two*** earlier instances of ***emphasis / emphases*** in immediately preceding text it all makes much more sense. Taken as a whole it's relatively dense text dealing with relatively complicated ideas, so I wouldn't necessarily say it's "not very elegantly written" - you sometimes need complex language to convey complex concepts, and obviously the writers can't be expected to make big concessions to people who might struggle with that in the context of what to them is a foreign language.

Comment: (I can't say offhand exactly *why*, but I can't help feeling a question like this should be Off Topic here on ELU.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard of pluralising emphasis before now... It's the context anyway, Horney, Fromm and Sullivan have partially arrived at various emphases on their own.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the sentence means that while Adler had a direct influence, the analysts in question also came to their own (similar) conclusions based on at least partially independent study.  Or to say it another way, study that wasn't directly based on Adler's work.

Your quote reminds me of [Charles Darwin and Alfred Russel Wallace.](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/history_14)  While they had some direct contact and possibly influenced one another, they arrived at many of the same conclusions "partially independently."

We also see this [concept explored](http://parallelthinkingcomedy.com/about/) by stand-up comedians who develop similar jokes by virtue of sharing similar influences.  This concept has been referred to as [parallel thinking](https://medium.com/@MichaelTunnell/did-amy-schumer-steal-jokes-or-was-it-parallel-thinking-fabc20e9e13c) recently.